# Reference passed to a method

Tags: c++, class, reference

why would anyone create and call a method which has it's own class as an input parameter? isn't simpler to just do `ob.a = x` if we want to assign/change the value? what is the advantage and disadvantage?

```
class Test
{
    public int a, b;

    public Test(int i, int j)
    {
        a = i;
        b = j;
    }

    public void Change(Test junk)
    {
        junk.a = junk.a + junk.b;
        junk.b = -junk.b;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test ob = new Test(15,20);
        Console.WriteLine("ob.a and ob.b before call: " + ob.a + " " + ob.b);
        ob.Change(ob);
        Console.WriteLine("ob.a and ob.b after call: " + ob.a + " " + ob.b);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot access private and protected members of a class directly through an object**. Only public variables can be accessed through the object.

So, if you want to change the private/protected data members there is a need of member functions.

Comment: if I make the class variables (a, b) to be private, I can't run ob.Change.

Comment: You can run ob.change() mehtod, no one stops you from doing that, i mean you can call it from main as it is a public member function.

Comment: I think OP was asking the reverse of this question.  Not why use member methods, but why would a class have static methods operating on its own class.

Comment: But he din't mentioned static anywhere, To answer that question, making a method static which accepts a class type is not recommended, as static method is not belongs to an object level, it belongs to a class.